# yii manage sub table's data in form

Tags: php, yii

I am working on YII framework, and I am a newbie.
I have user register form as shown below:

Username: [Textbox]

Email: [Textbox]

Address: [Text area]

User Loan Type: (Checkbox list as below)

- Loan Type 1
- Loan Type 2
- Loan Type 3
- Loan Type 4
- Loan Type 5

Status [yes/no]

Now I have 3 models:

1) User (for user data)

2) LoanType (just for loan type list)

3) UserLoanType (mapping between user and loan type)

All 3 models have HAS_MANY and BELONGS_TO relations as we generally do in YII.

Now when user click on register button I want to save data in user_loan_type table as well. I can simply add core php logic in actionCreate. But is there any standard YII practice for this?? Because I need validation, remain form selected during edit etc. Can anyone guide me how to do this? Or point me any example link, I have googled but did't help.

Thanks.

---

I am able to save data in database,
Now during edit I want to retrieve 3rd table's(tbl_user_loan_request_type) data. I have used below code.

```
$user = User::model()->findByPk(5); 
    print_r($user->UserLoanTypes);
```

But it is giving me blank array.
Where I am wrong??

Answer (score 1):

You may define afterSave methods in your class, like this:

Model User

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'UserLoanTypes' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'LoanType', 'UserLoanType(userId, loanId)'),
    );
}

// relation
        array('UserLoanTypes', 'safe'),

// label
        'UserLoanTypes' => 'User Loan Type'

protected function afterSave()
{
    parent::afterSave();
    UserLoanType::model()->deleteAll('userId=:id', array(':id' => $this->id));
    foreach ($this->UserLoanTypes  as $loanId) {
         $userLoanType = new UserLoanType();
         $userLoanType->userId = $this->id;
         $userLoanType->loadId = $loadId;
         $userLoanType->save();
    }
}

protected function afterDelete()
{
    parent::afterDelete();
    UserLoanType::model()->deleteAll('userId=:id', array(':id' => $this->id));
}
```

In form:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'UserLoanTypes'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'UserLoanTypes', CHtml::listData($LoanTypes, 'id', 'loanName')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'UserLoanTypes'); ?>
</div>
```

In view you may:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'UserLoanTypes' => array(
            'name'  => 'UserLoanTypes',
            'value' => implode(',', CHtml::listData($model->UserLoanTypes, 'id', 'name')),
        ),
     ),
   )); ?>
```

Comment: Mixing createCommand and CActiveRecord is not the best approach when working with the framework :S

Comment: Instead of using deleteAll method, you can define new relation to access UserLoanType rows and delete each one of them :)

Comment: @sucotronic, deleteAll deleted by one query, instead many if delete each one

Comment: I know is less efficient, but safer and object oriented :P You can also wrap it into a transaction and it will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to assign multiple loanTypes to one User, it would be easier. All you need is the User model for the form visualization:

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'user-form',
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Username'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Email'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Address'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'Address'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Address'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'UserLoanType'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model,'idLoanType', CHtml::listData(LoanType::model()->findAll, 'id', 'name')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'UserLoanTypes'); ?>
</div>


<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```